# How to solve $(1+x)^{y+1}=(1-x)^{y-1}$ for $x$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $y \in [0,1]$ is some constant, and $x \in [y,1]$. How to solve the following equation for $x$:

$\frac{1+y}{2}\log_2(1+x)+\frac{1-y}{2}\log_2(1-x)=0$ ?

Or equivalently $1+x = (1-x)^{\frac{y-1}{y+1}}$?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm, try one of the endpoints.

EDIT: with the new version of the question, I doubt that the solution can be expressed
in "closed form".  However, there appears to be a series solution
$$x = 2\,y-\frac{4}{3}\,{y}^{3}+{\frac {8}{45}}\,{y}^{5}+{\frac {32}{945}}\,{y}^{7}+
{\frac {736}{14175}}\,{y}^{9} + \ldots $$

Comment: (+1): I was about to comment that that didn't work...and then I checked the *other* endpoint. /facepalm/

Comment: The question has changed (:()and this is no longer a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

$x = y = 0$ is an obvious solution. Check how the above behave as you move away from that point.

Comment: Note that when $y = 1/2$, $x = 0.839287\ldots$ is a solution....

Comment: Need a numerical method to solve this... just iterating $x_{n + 1} = (1 - x_n)^{(y - 1)/(y + 1)} - 1$ for given $y$ should work, starting with $x_0 = (1 - y) / (1 + y)$.

Comment: It does depend on the $y$; when rational, we can get a polynomial equation without much trouble, and it may even be feasible to solve!

Comment: @Hurkyl, OK, let's take $y = 113 /355$ for a random example...

Comment: @vonbrand: See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we set $f = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ and $\eta = \frac{y+1}{2}$ some manipulation yields the following:

$$2f^{\eta} - f - 1 = 0$$

For rational $\eta = \frac{p}{q}$, this can be converted to a polynomial in $f^{\frac{1}{q}}$, and is likely "unsolveable" exactly, and would require numerical methods (like Newton-Raphson etc, which will work for irrational $\eta$ too).